# Перебор вложенных списков по разным индексам, собранным в одном списке

Tags: python, list, циклы, индексы

Как перебрать вложенные списки с несколькими элементами по индексам, собранным в одном отдельном списке? **Один индекс = перебор одного вложенного списка**. Все полученные элементы собрать в одну переменную.

Получилось найти одновременно несколько элементов по нескольким индексам, но только по одному списку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть список состоящий из нескольких вложенных списков в которых находятся 32 буквы русского алфавита в виде отдельных элементов. И есть индексы , например [2, 23, 18, 19 ]. Количество вложенных списков равно количеству индексов. Один индекс на перебор одного вложенного списка. С каждого вложенного списка надо по индексу взять один элемент и всех собрать в одной переменной

Comment: Ссори не 32 буквы а столько букв в одном вложенном списке сколько индексов

Comment: У меня получается только сбор всех элементов по индексу но только по одному вложенному списку. А мне надо - один индекс перебор одного списка и так по циклу. В итоге в одной переменной собраны все элементы по одному из каждого. Проблема в том что индексы в одном списке а перебор идет по нескольким

Comment: Ну вы бы хоть пример кода и списков привели, а то нужно отвечающим всё выдумывать

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [[i*10+j for j in range(6)] for i in range(4)]
print(a)
b = [3,1,5,0]
c = [a[k][b[k]] for k in range(len(b))]
print(c)
```

Главное для вас - использование элемента списка индексов как второго индекса очередного подсписка a[]: `a[k][b[k]]`

Если непонятно, что делает `c=[...]` - это генератор списка, эквивалент цикла

```
c = []
for k in range(len(b)):
    c.append([a[k][b[k]])
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], 
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]

[3, 11, 25, 30]
```