# перебор вложенных списков по разным индексам

Tags: list, циклы, индексы

Как перебрать вложенные списки с несколькими элементами по по индексам собранным в одном отдельном списке. Один индекс перебор одного вложенного списка. Все полученные элементы собрать в одну переменную. Получилось найти одновременно несколько элементов по нескольким индексам но только по одному списку. Есть список состоящий из нескольких вложенных списков в которых находятся буквы русского алфавита в виде отдельных элементов. И есть индексы , например [2, 23, 18, 19 ]. Количество вложенных списков равно количеству индексов. Один индекс на перебор одного вложенного списка. С каждого вложенного списка надо по индексу взять один элемент и всех собрать в одной переменной. У меня получается только сбор всех элементов по индексу но только по одному вложенному списку. А мне надо - один индекс перебор одного списка и так по циклу. В итоге в одной переменной собраны все элементы по одному из каждого. Проблема в том что индексы в одном списке а перебор идет по нескольким

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: началось время всяких олимпиад, что ли?

Comment: да дубликат. не в том аккаунте задал

Comment: можете мне помочь?

Comment: зачем тебе помогать, если ты никак не реагируешь на уточняющие вопросы и ответы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос пример списков, индексов и требуемый ответ.

Comment: [['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л], ['Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н'], ['В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З'], 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К'], ['Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'Ч']]

Comment: а вот список с индексами [2, 3,  4, 5, 7]. Нужен один элемент с каждого идущего по порядку вложенному списку согласно индекса. один индекс на один список. 5 индексов тогда 5 элементов всего но из разных списков. все это сложить в одну переменную

Comment: выглядеть должно так:

Comment: spisok = "ВДЖИЛ"

Answer (score 1):

```
''.join(lst[i] for i, lst in zip(indices, lists))
```

Comment: Классный однострочник)

Comment: огромное спасибо. а пояснения не смогли бы дать для дальнейшего моего развития

Answer (score 0):

```
awd = []
j = 0
for i in range(len(asdf)):
    awd.append(etters[j][asdf[i]])
    `введите сюда код`j += 1
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Салават В [более раннем вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1545191/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5) же есть ответ. Потрудитесь принять ответ как решение.

Comment: это решение на мой собственный вопрос. на 5 строчке текст введите сюда код попал случайно. показал я его сюда чтобы показать одно из решений. не могу тягаться с однострочником. но все же может кому то и пригодится или объяснят что не так

Comment: @Салават Суть этого ответа я дал с рабочим примером в вашей прошлой ветке, и растолковал, когда вы об этом попросили. Так что сходите туда и примите там мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer, а здесь примите ответ Станислава, работающий по другому принципу.